# Django: error with logging module when running any manage.py command

Tags: python, django, module, pip

OSX, Python 2.7, pip, virtualenv. Been using these for years with no issues.

I'm not sure what changed, but recently my environment completely broke for Django after working perfectly fine for a while. The same checkout runs fine on my friend's computer with a similar setup.

Things I've already tried: deleting my venv and creating a new one with fresh installs from requirements.txt, uninstalling logging outside the venv and reinstalling inside, reinstalling pip.

I get the same traceback for any manage.py command. It appears to be having issues with the logging module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in     execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 376, in execute
    sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + '\n')
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 242, in main_help_text
    for name, app in six.iteritems(get_commands()):
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in _configure_logging
    logging_config_func(DEFAULT_LOGGING)
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/utils/dictconfig.py", line 555, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Users/rfong/Dropbox/code/lattis_workspace/lattis_repo/venv/lib/python2.    7/site-packages/django/utils/dictconfig.py", line 323, in configure
    del logging._handlerList[:]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'
```

Comment: you can try inspecting  `logging.__file__` value just before error occurs, to find out what logging module is being used. don't you have a file logging.py somwhere on you pythonpath?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention logging.__file__ =
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/logging-0.4.9.6-py2.7.egg/logging/__init__.pyc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you installed outdated `0.4.9.6` version of logging module, presumably with `pip`. Correct version, shipped with python 2.7 is `0.5.1.2`, and I suppose in your case might be located in `/Library/Python/2.7/lib/logging`. Correct version can be uploaded from [python svn](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/logging/).

If you use pip, you always can find out which module versions are installed with

```
$ pip freeze
```

to ensure that correct versions of packages are installed, use following syntax:

```
$ pip install <package>==<version>
```

this will save you lot of pain and efforts, and almost a must on production environments.

Comment: I have not been able to find 0.5.1.2 in the 2.7 libs or pypi. Is there a way to get it short of reinstalling python?

Comment: Whoops, didn't see your link. Thanks for the tip, it works when I place that version of logging in my venv site-packages! But I'm not sure how to _properly_ install it since it lacks a setup.py. What's the appropriate procedure there?

Comment: there is no `properly install procedure` for such a simple module without a build process. you can just place it in python/lib (as it was meant to be there) or in venv